# Highcharts pane background does not appear

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I used highcharts to create chart of type "solidgauge". As per the docs, I gave assigned a background object to the pane object. The graph draws perfectly fine, except that the pane background does not appear! This is the code snippet of the pane object.

```js
pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: Background
      },
```

And below is the code of the Background object

```js
let Background = [] as any;
    if (this.props.dataSource.values.Rows) {
      this.props.dataSource.values.Rows.forEach((row: any, index: number) => {
        Background.push({
          outerRadius: `${100 - index * 20}%`,
          innerRadius: `${90 - index * 20}%`,
          backgroundColor: "",
          borderWidth: 0
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Piyush Pareek, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xfcka1zg/, the pane with `backgorund` option seems to work correctly.